# Move UIView in x position with jumps

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I need your help. I am trying to move my view in x position. When I use a normal UIView Animation for this, the view will be moved from one x to the other x position.

But my intention is that the view is moved from the old x to the new x but not points by points. Instead it should go each 20 points oder something like this. You understand me?

This image should help you understand me:
[image]

I appreciate any tips and clues

Best regards from Germany,
Chris

Comment: So you want the view to animate 20 points to the left, pause, left, pause...repeat?

Comment: I want the view to be moved from x=0 to x= -20 to x= -40. Between this x's position the view should be hidden :)

Comment: I need it for a LED Display so that the font is just on the points and not between ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about chaining animations?

You create an animation that reduces the x of the frame by 20:

```
CGRect frame = myView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x - 20.0;
myView.frame = frame;
```

Create an animation with this, chain it in the completion block until x is the final point. Use a delay between the animations.

Comment: So you would use this with a NSTimer Object?

Comment: Can you post an example of your idea...Would be great :)

Comment: For example, or you can use perform:WithDelay: after the end of every animation

Comment: But with NSTimer how would you know that it reached -20 before it should fire again. Timer will fire non-stop

Comment: Okay...smart idea...I'll check it out :)